# Close Dialog loading progress

Tags: flutter

Error: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3580 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.

dialog bar shows but there is an error when closing the dialog ... is there any other way to close?

```
class Dialogs {
  static Future<void> showLoadingDialog(
      BuildContext context, GlobalKey key) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new WillPopScope(
              onWillPop: () async => false,
              child: SimpleDialog(
                  key: key,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center(
                      child: Column(children: [
                        CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Text("Carregando....",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),)
                      ]),
                    )
                  ]));
        });
  }
}


Future<void> _carregaLugares(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
  
    PlacesSearchResponse response = await places.searchNearbyWithRankBy(Location(latitude, longitude), 'distance');
    print(response.status);
    setState(() {
      if (response.status == "OK") {
        lugares = response.results;
        _saving = false;
      }
    });
      Navigator.of(_keyLoader.currentContext,rootNavigator: true).pop();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

call dialog

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      Dialogs.showLoadingDialog(context, _keyLoader);
    });
....
```

Answer (score 0):

// Hide

Navigator.of(_keyLoader.currentContext,rootNavigator: true).pop();